# calc command line tool always becomes interactive

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew

For some reason calc always becomes interactive (as if I had specified -i, or not specified an expression at all). I have to press CTRL-C multiple times to exit.

```
~ calc 5+4
    9
^C
[Abort level 1]
^C
[Abort level 2]
^C
[Abort level 3]
^C
ABORT
~
```

It worked fine on my old mac. I installed it using brew (on both machines), and reinstalling calc doesnt help. What could be the reason?

Edit: I've tried starting a clean bash shell, I've checked aliases, and I've tried to use `-q -e` to ignore environment and configuration files. None of these things have helped.

```
~ type -a calc
calc is /usr/local/bin/calc
```

`~ calc -q -e 5+4` does not change the behaviour.

```
~ env -i bash --noprofile --norc
bash-3.2$ calc 5+4
```

doesnt help either.

```
~ ls -l /usr/local/bin/calc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lafp  admin  34 Feb 28 14:43 /usr/local/bin/calc -> ../Cellar/calc/2.12.7.1_1/bin/calc`
```

I did find something that *does* help. Switching to a different user! (in this case root).

```
~ sudo su
root@... calc 5+4
    9
root@...
```

Comment: I have checked for aliases: `calc is /usr/local/bin/calc`. Did you see anything in the documentation that mentions startup files? I didnt...

Comment: I also tried running with a clean environment (`env -i /usr/local/bin/calc 5+5`), and it gave the same result.

Comment: Even starting a clean bash session (`env -i bash --noprofile --norc`) doesnt help.

Comment: I had no idea calc had startup files, sorry for not checking myself. Unfortunately -q -e didnt help (I dont have any custom startup files). 

No, I meant that I got stuck in interactive mode, just as before.
I have updated the question.

Comment: Switching to a different user (root) seems to help... Updated the question.

Comment: root may use different `$PATH` and therefore different version of `calc`. Investigate this.

Comment: I checked, they both use /usr/local/bin/calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out: the problem was rvm.

In my .bash_profile I had `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

And it stayed loaded even when starting a new bash or clearing environment variables, because `env -i` does not clear functions, only variables.

Needless to say I will try to avoid rvm in the future... it registers hundreds of functions. Scary.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

On zsh, `calc` is a function. You may try that instead of `/usr/local/bin/calc`

```
$ which calc
calc () {
    awk "BEGIN{ print $* }"
}
```

Option 2:
Try running command with absolute path. `/usr/local/bin/calc 5+4` or `\calc 5+4`. If `\calc` worked for you then most probably you have set an alias for `calc`.

Comment: Using a function works! Still dont understand why it is necessary but it works! Using an absolute path (or `\calc`) does not make any difference.